# jump forward in jQuery animation?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to jump a jQuery animation forward / backward in time?

For example, if I have set an animation on an element to take 10 seconds, can I jump to '5 seconds' into that animation?  Preferably, this could be set with a percentage.

Comment: You can't make an animation progress further along it's path *using documented methods* (i'm sure there's a way to do it using undocumented methods, but i wouldn't recommend it), however you can stop a queue and make it continue on the next method in the queue.

Comment: You could also create a plugin to simply do the math that the animation is already doing, stop it and than continue from the selected point. If you give me a demo, i'll do it.

Comment: @A.M.K http://jsfiddle.net/nh5JP/ thx!

Comment: I finished it, you can do the percentages by simply dividing the animation speed by 100 then multiplying by whatever percentage you want it to go to.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the current animation, set the state of the animated object to halfway between its initial state and final state and then start a new animation to the original final state, but set for half the time.

That will jump to the halfway position of the animation and then continue going from there.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/FjqKW/.

Comment: Would need to hack into the easing functions too.

Comment: @jedierikb - Easiest with linear easing - no hacking required.  See the working example I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/queue/

you could try to set up a queue in your animation OR

if you could provide an example surely you could receive a good hint ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should have everything you want but the percentage functionality:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/MHV5k/

jQuery:

```
var time = 10000; // Animation speed in ms
var opacity = 0; // Final desired opacity


function jumpAnimate(setOpacityTo, newOpacity, speed){  // I created a function to simplify things
    $("#fade").css("opacity", setOpacityTo).animate({
        "opacity": newOpacity
    }, {
        duration: speed // I used speed instead of time because time is already a global variable
    });
}

$("#jump").click(function(){
    var goTo = $("#jump-to").val(); // Get value from the text input

    var setOpacity = (1 / time) * (time - goTo); /* The opacity that the element should be set at, i.e. the actual jump
    Math is as follows: initial opacity / the speed of the original animation in ms * the time minus the desired animation stop in ms (basically the remaining time past the desired point) */

    $("#fade").stop(); // Stop the original animation after the math is finished so that we have minimal delay

    jumpAnimate(setOpacity, opacity, time - goTo); // Start a new animation
});

jumpAnimate(1, opacity, time);​ // Start the initial animation
```