# How do you speed up an animation mid animation with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Suppose you have an animation running with a certain time like this:

```
$('span').animate({opacity : 1}, 10000);
```

The animation is quite long so the user tries clicking the button again. The animation will be a certain amount of time through the animation already, which is probably going to be different every time.

On the second click is it possible to update the animation process keeping the opacity of the object when the user clicks, just changing the time it will take to finish?

Basically I want to update the animation process mid way through the animation.

Comment: Interesting question, but... Why do you want the slow animation in the first place? I can't think of terribly many good reasons for anything that's going to slow down your users' ability to navigate your web page.

Comment: You could use the step function http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1856-Using-jQuery-s-Animate-Step-Callback-Function-To-Create-Custom-Animations.htm

Comment: OK, done. It needed to be reversed for fading-in animations instead of fading-out animations and to speed up instead of skipping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `step` option of `animate` to keep track of how far along the animation is.  Then with that information, you can calculate the time remaining in the animation.  Then stop the current animation and start a new one with half the duration.

http://jsfiddle.net/MdD45/

**EDIT**

It looks like the 2nd parameter passed to `step` contains a property named `pos` which tells you what percentage along in the animation you are.  That can simplify things further.

http://jsfiddle.net/MdD45/1/

```
var startVal = 0;
var endVal = 1;
var duration = 10000;

var howfar = 0;

$('span').css("opacity",startVal)
    .animate({
        opacity : endVal
    }, {
        duration: duration,
        step: function(now, fx){
            howfar = fx.pos;  // between 0 and 1, tells how far along %
        }        
    });

$("button").click(function(){
    // calculate the new duration as half of the remaining duration
    var timeRemaining = duration - (howfar * duration);
    duration = timeRemaining / 2;

    $('span').stop().animate({
        opacity : endVal
    }, {
        duration: duration,
        step: function(now, fx){
            howfar = fx.pos;  // between 0 and 1, tells how far along %
        }        
    });
});
​
```

Comment: I really think that it is the best way to go. `step` is a pretty under-used, but immensely powerful add-on to jQuery animations.

Comment: I think both of our solutions are perfectly usable and would possibly benchmark out the same, but, mine delivers a usable time in ms. And, as demonstrated, mine is also adaptable.

Comment: I concede, I just tested yours backwards and it runs perfectly without any modification. It should also work on any animation. Permission to copy and use?

Comment: @A.M.K Hah, sure, use away.  Now that it's on SO it doesn't really belong to me anyway.  Also, my comment on your question was by no means implying that my answer was better, simply pointing out a useful property that you could use to simplify your calculation.

Comment: Wonderful! I never even thought of using step!

Answer (score 2):

<s>I put something together yesterday to [skip in jQuery animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414191/jump-forward-in-jquery-animation/12415095#12415095), here's the code, it should be pretty easy to modify for your use-case:</s>

**EDIT**: Modified version:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/fJyKM/

jQuery:

```
var time = 10000;
var opacity = 1;
var currentTime = 0;

$("#square").animate({
    opacity: opacity
}, {
    duration: time,
    step: function(now, fx) {

        currentTime = Math.round((now * time) / opacity);

    },
    easing: "linear"
});


$("#hurry").click(function() {
    $("#square").stop().animate({
        opacity: opacity
    }, {
        duration: ((time - currentTime) / 4), // Get remaining time, divide by 4
        step: function(now, fx) {

            currentTime = Math.round((now * time) / opacity);

        },
        easing: "linear"
    });
});​
```

It also works for other properties, like [width](http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/bd3Dj/). The only catch is that if it is a *decreasing* value than you need to use a [different script](http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/MHV5k/).

Comment: The `fx.pos` property removes the need for the currentTime calcuation.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can ..

You have to stop the animation with "stop()" method then start a new animation against the same node on the same property and as a target value, the original one.

Comment: Obviously you will have to change the duration ... see api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: But how do you know the time remaining on the first animation to know how quickly the 2nd animation should last?

Comment: Since you are catching a click event, you could manage to compute the new duration with a formula before launching the new animation ... This is okey for a linear effect but might be not what you would like to achieve if the easing function is a none linear one :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure if this would work, but consider doing like this:

```
<div id="box"></div>
<style type="text/css">
div#box {
    -webkit-transition: width 10s;
    -moz-transition: width 10s;
    transition: width 10s;
    background: #000;
    width: 100px;
}
div#box.speedy {
    -webkit-transition: width 5s;
    -moz-transition: width 5s;
    transition: width 5s;
}
</style>
<script style="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('div#box').css('width', '400');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('div#box').addClass('box');
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

Basicly let css animate it, and add another class that speeds the transition up.

Comment: `.addClass` not being an animation means that it will not wait for the `delay`.